# Strange Counter - HackerRank

Tags: java

Here is the link to the problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/strange-code/problem

```
static long strangeCounter(long t) {
        long i,c=1;
        long cl=2;
        HashMap<Long,Long> map = new HashMap<Long,Long>();
        while(c>t){
            if(cl<3){
                cl=3;
            }else{
                cl=cl*2;
            }
            for(i=cl;i>0;i--){
                map.put(c,cl);
                c++;
                //if(c>t) break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map); //For debug... It is printing {} 
        return map.get(t);
    }
```

This hashmap is showing null where as I am trying to store the time counter in a map. Why is it showing null?

Comment: If it's printing {}, that's not the same as "showing null" at all. It's showing an empty map, which suggests that maybe your `t` is 0 or less. It's hard to tell beyond that. I'd suggest stepping through the code in a debugger. (I'd also suggest that you might want to add more spaces in your code, to benefit readability - e.g. `for (i = cl; i > 0; i--) {` instead of `for(i=cl;i>0;i--){`. Readability is subjective, but my experience is that spaces like that are generally preferred.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it is an empty map, but I have given value of t as 5, but still map remains empty.

Comment: My point is that "This hashmap is showing null" and "This hashmap is showing empty" are very different statements. As I said, your next step should be to step through the code in a debugger. I made a mistake in my "maybe t is 0 or less" though - currently your while loop only executes while `c` is greater than `t`, and `c` starts off as 1. So if `t` is 5, it's never going to enter the loop body. Again, you should be able to see that by stepping through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet. It was a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

The Map is not null, it is empty.  The map is empty because nothing ever gets put in it.

- If the value `t` is 1 or greater then you never enter the `while`
  loop.  This produces an empty Map.
- If the value `t` is 0 (or less) you will never produce an answer
  since the while-loop will never end (gracefully) as you only
  increment `c` and `t` never changes.